# Training neural network on gradient of input with pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, autograd, jax

I am currently trying to train a neural network with pytorch, where I try to match the input on the input derivative. I want to do this because this is ensuring a conservative vector field. (Done in training of neural networks for force matching in molecular dynamics)
This means:

```
input = torch.rand((n,3),requires_grad=True)
output = torch.rand((n,3),requires_grad=True)
prediction = model(input) # size of the prediction[1]
input_grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=prediction, inputs=input, retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)
loss = loss_fn(output,input_grad)
...
```

The problem is, that if I try to update the parameters of the neural network, the gradient in all parameters is 0. I made sure that the model is working properly; I don't know how to build the graph that the model is training properly.
In Jaxmd, it is possible to train a model like this as shown [Jax Glass Training][1].
I've also tried

```
input_grad = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=prediction, inputs=input, create_graph=True)
```

but this yields to similar results and does not make sense.
[1]: https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/jax-md/blob/master/notebooks/neural_networks.ipynb#scrollTo=WNs8v2745Mc3

EDIT:

updated code example for reproduction pytorch version 1.6.0

```
import torch 

class Feedforward(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
            super(Feedforward, self).__init__()
            self.input_size = input_size
            self.hidden_size  = hidden_size
            self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
            self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
            self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
     
        
        def forward(self, x):
            hidden = self.fc1(x)
            relu = self.relu(hidden)
            output = self.fc2(relu)
            output = output.sum()
            output =torch.autograd.grad(outputs=output, inputs=x, retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)
            return output[0]

test_input = torch.rand((10,3),requires_grad=True)
test_output = torch.rand((10,3))


model = Feedforward(3,10)
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
optim.zero_grad()
loss_fn = torch.nn.L1Loss()
model.train()
out = model(test_input)
loss = loss_fn(out, test_output)
loss.backward()
optim.step() # if you break here and investigate the gradients
             # of the FFNN, the gradients will be 0
```

Comment: A derivative is defined for a function with respect to an independent variable of that function. When you say "input derivative", what function are you referring to and what independent variable of that function are you trying to get the derivative with respect to? The reason I ask is because it's not clear by the code or your comments what you mean by input derivative.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. To pack it in context: Estimating the molecular Energy function U(x,phi) with a neural network, I want to match the forces F = -dU/dx and learn the parameter phi of the function. I thought this is clear, by defining the outputs and inputs of the torch.autograd.grad() function